# Relation Limit [ octobercms ]

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-plugins, october-partial

I have a model called `Lessons` and it has a `belongsToMany` relationship called `students` with a table called `students_for_lesson`. Lesson model has fields called `number_of_students` and `number_of_enrollments` for each lesson.

what I want is to give a message stopping Add students for the lesson when `number_of_enrollments` value reaches `number_of_students` value.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to listen to the Model relation events (  `BelongsToMany` ) : [beforeAttach](https://octobercms.com/docs/api/model/relation/beforeattach), [afterAttach](https://octobercms.com/docs/api/model/relation/afterattach), [beforeDetach](https://octobercms.com/docs/api/model/relation/beforedetach), [afterDetach](https://octobercms.com/docs/api/model/relation/afterdetach)

In this case if you need to run some validations before creating the relationship then use the `beforeAttach`event:

```
LessonModel::extend(function ($model) {

    /** Before Attach */
    $model->bindEvent('model.relation.beforeAttach', function ($relationName, $attachedIdList, $insertData) use ($model) {

        // Student => Lesson Relation
        if ($relationName === 'your-lesson-student-relation-name') {

            // Check Number of enrollments & other stuff ...

            // throw new \ApplicationException('Cannot add student. Maximum number of enrollments reached.');
        }

    });

});
```

See this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43519060/how-to-listen-for-relation-add-events) & here about [extending models](https://octobercms.com/docs/plugin/extending#extending-user-model)